# Prove M is open on the subspace ($A \cup B$).

Tags: general-topology

$(X,T)$ is a topological space, $A,B $ not empty subsets. If $M \subset A \cap B$, and $M$ is simultaneously open in relative topologies $ $ $\left.T\right|_{A}$ and $ $ $\left.T\right|_{B}$. Prove M is open on the subspace $(A \cup B,\left.T\right|_{(A \cup B)})$

Attempt : Trying to reach $M=G \cap (A \cup B)$ from the expression $M= G_1 \cap A$, $M=G_2 \cap  B$, but i couldn't reach it. Also trying to prove $G_1=G_2=G$ so we have reached that. And $ \mathring{A}=A$ in $A \cup B$ topology but nothing..

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Trying to reach $M=G \cap (A \cup B)$ from the expression $M= G_1 \cap A$, $M=G_2 \cap  B$, but i couldn't reach it. Also trying to prove $G_1=G_2=G$ so we have reached that. And $ \mathring{A}=A$ in $A \cup B$ topology but nothing..

Comment: Need to show more work before anyone will help you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $M=A\cap t_A=B\cap t_B$ where $t_A$ and $t_B$ belong to $T.$

We have $t_A\cap t_B\in T.$

Now $M\subset t_A$  and $M\subset t_B.$ So $M\subset (t_A\cap t_B).$ And $M\subset A\cup B.$ Therefore $$M\subset
(t_A\cap t_B)\cap (A\cup B)=$$ $$=[(t_A\cap t_B)\cap A]\,\cup \, [(t_A\cap t_B)\cap B]=$$ $$=
[t_B\cap (t_A\cap A)]\,\cup \,[t_A\cap (t_B\cap B)]=$$ $$=[t_B\cap M]\,\cup \,[t_A\cap M]\subset$$ $$\subset [M]\cup [M]=M.$$

Therefore $M=(t_A\cap t_B)\cap (A\cup B)\in T_{A\cup B}.$